# How to Transfer app ids from one account to another in Twitter and Fabric

Tags: ios, twitter, twitter-fabric

Is it possible to transfer app ids owned by one Twitter and Fabric account to another without change serial key and secret?

Answer (score 3):

Mike from Fabric here.

If you're looking to transfer an app to a different organization within Fabric, along with the existing history, then that is not currently possible.

Fabric API keys are set per organization.

Comment: Hello mike sorry for this question being asked here, but anyway its related... My fabric plugin in android doesn't recognize the app from new account, instead it redirects to the old account's oauth page. Need some help here

Comment: Since it's a different question, I'd raise it up as another SO question or post on TwitterCommunity.com in following best practices of SO.